# Hibernate. Why copyValues is called during merge event for PERSISTENT entities?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, orm

I was looking through the source code of [Hibernate 5.6](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/5.6) and found an interesting detail. In the [DefaultMergeEventListener](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultMergeEventListener.java#L209) class the `copyValues` method is called during the `entityIsPersistent` method invocation.
It's odd that `entity` and `target` parameters are equal to the same entity that is already persisted. Therefore, Hibernate copies the entity's attributes to the same memory spot it was copied from. Seems like that operation just burns CPU cycles and does no benefit.

Is that copying necessary, if we know that the passed entity is already persisted? BTW, the latest change in this line of code [was on 23 Nov 2013](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/241868e1dd4e9b31a0d03d2e0de2b8684b4f80fc#diff-0e7c6d5ca15c094d82414526c4efcbd65dd6098f206f56849305e8ba6bf96fc1R183) (and it was the checkstyle cleanup). Maybe it's just legacy stuff that should be removed?

P.S. I posted this discussion originally in Hibernate repository itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you mentioned calls [TypeHelper#replace()](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/TypeHelper.java#L106) that does not do a simple copy of `entity` into `target` but it executes a replacement.

Comment: Anyway, the `source` and `target` are the same

Comment: but in such a case the method does not do a copy, but it may replace some values.

Comment: if source equals to destination, how can it replace old values with something new?

Comment: if you think this method call is useless, you can just remove the call and then run all the Hibernate test suite and you will see few test failing.

Comment: That's a point. But I don't claim that it's useless. I'm wondering. And if it's not useless, I wan't to understand its purpose.

Comment: one case when it is important to call `Type.replace()` is by example for uninitialized collections because this method replaces any detached entities in the queued operations
with managed copies.